# Unity getter setter limitation doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using getter/setter for limiting a value. It's input.deltaPosition.x, player can rotate planet but I don't want to player insanely slide his finger and rotate the planet like 654654321 degrees. So I declared a variable and getter/setter. But still the value takes 650+ values or negative of it.

```
if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {                
                TouchX = touch.deltaPosition.x;
                transform.Rotate(0, yMultiplier * TouchX * Time.deltaTime * planetSpeed, 0, Space.World);
}
```

This is getter/setter

```
private float TouchX
    {
        get { return touchX; }
        set
        {
            if (touchX > 10)
                touchX = 10;
            else if (touchX < -10)
                touchX = -10;
            else
                touchX = value;
        }
    }
```

What I am doing wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: You arent checking the new value you're checking the current one..

Comment: OWWWWWWW OMG I am really blind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides you not checking `value` as you have already figured actually your code can be simplified a lot by simply using [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html)

```
private float TouchX
{
    get { return touchX; }
    set
    {
        touchX = Mathf.Clamp(value, -10, 10);
    }
}
```